# Scrolling through and getting the element

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I want to scroll a particular div and identify my element.
I tried all these ways found
here my element is the element I want after scrolling

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)");
utils.doubleClick(myelement);
```

Using send keys and action class also i tried but nothing works
Still, I am not able to identify my element
Can someone suggest other ways to do so

```
<div id="emTemplate:cpTree::db" class="x13q" _afrcolcount="1" style="position: relative; width: 172px; overflow: hidden; height: 246px; z-index: 1;">

    <table cellspacing="0" _rowcount="144" _startrow="91" summary="Target Tree" style="position: relative;">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="65"></tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="66"></tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="67"></tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="68"></tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="69"></tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="70"></tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="71"></tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="72"></tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="73"></tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="74">
                <td class="x1bv" nowrap="" _afrndcol="1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="75">
                <td class="x1bv" nowrap="" _afrndcol="1">
                    <div style="padding-left:64px;white-space:nowrap;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="xwr" style="padding:0px" _afrap="0_1_2_3" _afrrk="76">
                <td class="x1bv" nowrap="" _afrndcol="1">
                    <div style="padding-left:64px;white-space:nowrap;">
                        <span class="xx0" _afrnddth="4" _afrdisimg="0"></span>
                        <span id="emTemplate:cpTree:76:grypgl1" class="x1a">
                            <img id="emTemplate:cpTree:76:gryi1" class="xni" src="/em/images/soacomposite_ena.png" style="width:16px; height:16px; margin-right:3px; vertical-align:middle; cursor:pointer" alt="Oracle SOA Composite" title="Oracle SOA Composite"></img>
                            <span class="xe5" _afrndtxt="1">
                                <span id="emTemplate:cpTree:76:targetLink" class="" style="color: rgb(0, 42, 144); cursor: text;" title="/Farm_SOADomain/SOADomain/wls_soa1/default/PublishActualizedShipCost [2.1]"></span>
PublishActualizedShipCost [2.1]
```

This is the DOM and xpath used is:

```
//div[@id='emTemplate:cpTree::db']/table/tbody//tr/td/div/span/span/span[.='PublishActualizedShipCost [2.1]']
```

Plus there is no iframe as the elements on the index tr[1],tr[2] and all those visible without scrolling I am able to identify easily by just changing the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollIntoView to scroll the page till the element is found

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Scenario1Test.driver, 10); 
WebElement Element= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(" your xpath")));
      
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;      
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Element);
```

Comment: I tried this too. But it throws unable to find element as the element is down which gets identified only after i scroll.

Comment: Can you share url to replicate this issue ?

Comment: Actually it can be accessed over some VPN

Comment: Waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath("')(tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval) getting this

Comment: I checked and since the elements without scroll are easily identifiable and hence i dont think frame is an issue.

Comment: m.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='emTemplate:cpTree::db']/table/tbody//tr/td/div/span/span/span[@title=''title here"}

Comment: yes i tried to do
List<webelemnt> elemnt= driver.findelements(xpath).size
It returned me 1
but now its not able to perform any action on it

Comment: Initially you were saying you are getting NoSuchElementException exception and now you are said one element is found bit contradictory tbh..

Comment: yes yesterday it was not returning but now when i printed the size it returned 1

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", myelement);
```

The above code should work fine to scroll you to the element. Let me know if this helps!

If you are trying to scroll to 250 height, following is needed to be done:

```
long scrollHeight = 250;
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

Comment: before this code do i have to write 
Webelement myelement = driver.findelement(By.xpath("");

Comment: But if i write so it fails there only saying unable to find the element

Comment: In that case, are you using a wait till the page is loaded? because, element not found says that it is not in dom

Comment: this my element will contain xpath of the div or the element i want after scrolling the div?

Comment: element where you want to scroll to.. div will work if the element is withing the div

Comment: I added wait also but it shows unable to find element at that line only where i am writing webelement element =driver.findelement(By.xpath("")

Comment: Can you please publish the element you are trying to find and the DOM with the element?? This code is working and never throws this error unless the element is not there. Now all i can think of is that if there is some iframe, which is not letting the element to be present.

Comment: Hi i have edited the question with Xpath and dom
but xpath is correct only as the elements without scrolling they are easily identifiable.

Comment: Looks fine :(   Can you try changing xpath as //span[@id='emTemplate:cpTree:76:targetLink'] instead. Or else you have to debug and check the runtime availability of xpath. I am wondering if the square brackets in  PublishActualizedShipCost [2.1] is causing the issue.. It happened me once, where some special character caused issue.